# cursor logic in ssis

Tags: ssis

i have been strugling to convert the following t sql task into an automated ssis package.
i tried implementing using for loop conntainer but while creating the looping logic i am stucking off. i really appreciate of some one could help me out with logic

here is the t- sql code

```
-- SCRIPT TO BULK IMPORT MATERNAL HLA & INSERT CORD NIMA


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#maternal_hla_from_solar') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
      drop table #maternal_hla_from_solar
END

CREATE TABLE #maternal_hla_from_solar(
      [donor_id] [int] NOT NULL,
      [antigen_id] [int] NOT NULL
)

-- bulk upload maternal HLA from file
BULK
INSERT #maternal_hla_from_solar
FROM 'C:\Users\zabeenp\Documents\SQL\populate_db\data\20111212_maternal_hla.txt'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
MAXERRORS = 0,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

-- declare variables
DECLARE @donor_id int
DECLARE @maternal_hla varchar(5000)
DECLARE @definitive_type_date date = GETDATE()
DECLARE @modified_on datetime2(7) = GETDATE()

-- Cursor to process each row from #maternal_hla_from_solar
DECLARE c_insertCordNima CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR select DISTINCT donor_id from #maternal_hla_from_solar -- important to use DISTINCT here
OPEN c_insertCordNima
FETCH NEXT FROM c_insertCordNima INTO @donor_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      SET @maternal_hla = ''  -- important to wipe string each time

      -- concatenare maternal antigen_ids into one string
      SELECT @maternal_hla = COALESCE(@maternal_hla + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),antigen_id)
      FROM #maternal_hla_from_solar
      where donor_id = @donor_id

      -- remove first comma
      SET @maternal_hla = (select right(@maternal_hla,len(@maternal_hla)-1))

      -- exec insertCordNIMA SP
      EXECUTE insertCordNIMA
         @donor_id
        ,@maternal_hla
        ,@definitive_type_date
        ,@modified_on

      FETCH NEXT FROM c_insertCordNima INTO @donor_id
END
CLOSE c_insertCordNima
DEALLOCATE c_insertCordNima
```

Comment: Your question would be improved if you were to explain what the *purpose* of the code it. It looks like you are reading in a tab delimited file into a temporary table and then for each donor id, you are building a comma delimited string and then executing a stored proc.

Comment: purpose of the code is to run the stored procedure with mentioned parameters over agin and agin untill the last donor_id, here basically i have many antigen_ids with same donor_id , so i need to stingfy them before giving to the sp in each step with above logic. in my ssis package i am not able to bring the initial expression, checking expression  and increment expression for my for loop, please give me any idea on this which would replace WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 for my for_loop in ssis.

Comment: Why do you need to replace the cursor? If it works correctly and quickly enough then you can just put it into an Execute SQL task without changing it. A loop container in SSIS is usually used for looping over multiple files to import or similar purposes.

Comment: because i need to process over 9 million records so it is taking ages to do it. i found in some forums using the forloop instead of cursor will speed up the things,

Comment: So the real issue is the cursor, not SSIS? If so, the question becomes, can you re-write insertCordNIMA so that it processes all rows at once? There's no way to answer that without knowing what the logic/code in the procedure looks like. You need to give more information about the code, execution time, how often you need to run it etc. I suggest you edit your question or submit a completely new one with the "tsql" and "sql-server" tags, because SSIS does not seem to be the main issue here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to rewrite the cursor using a Recursive CTE?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx